# Minimal models in strong set theories

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, ordinals, large-cardinals

Given some theory $T$, let $M(T)$ denote the height of the minimal model of $T$, i.e. $\min\{\eta: L_\eta \vDash T\}$. Obviously there are some famous examples, e.g. $M(\textsf{KP}) = \omega$, and $M(\textsf{KPi})$ is the least recursively inaccessible. Now, according to "2.24, A zoo of ordinals", $M(\textsf{ZFC})$ is less than the least stable ordinal ($\min\{\eta: L_\eta \prec_{\Sigma_1} L\}$). I assume this is probably true. What happens if we consider stronger theories, e.g. ZFC + there exists an I0 cardinal, and are their $M$'s still less than the least stable ordinal? Or is there some large cardinal assumption we can add to ZFC that brings the $M$ of the theory to be $\geq$ the least stable ordinal, and if so, can we find what is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing like that can happen.

Note that as long as $T$ is reasonably simple (e.g. computably axiomatizable), the statement "There is a level of $L$ satisfying $T$" is  $\Sigma_1$ and so reflected along $\prec_{\Sigma_1}$. This means that for such a $T$, if in fact any levels of the $L$-hierarchy satisfy $T$, there must be such a level below the least stable ordinal: if $L_\eta\prec_{\Sigma_1}L$, then since $L\models$ "There is a level of $L$ satisfying $T$" we have $L_\eta\models$ "There is a level of $L$ satisfying $T$," and so some $\alpha<\eta$ must have $L_\alpha\models T$.

Comment: Oh, great! Thanks. But could it be possible that, if $T$ is not computably axiomatizable, this could happen?

Comment: If this could happen with an uncomputably axiomatizable theory, we would have an incredibly powerful theory on our hands, far beyond ZFC or MK. However, it would be extremely undescribable.

Comment: @Binary198 Well, $T$ would have to be *so* complicated that it's not $\Delta_1$ in the Levy hierarchy. That's a lot more than just "not computable" - for example, $T$ would have to be more complicated than true first-order arithmetic. (I think a more interesting thing to do is look at simple theories in stronger logics, but that's just me.)

Comment: I've heard about the Levy hierarchy, but I thought it only applied to formulas. What would it mean for a theory to be $\Pi_n$, $\Sigma_n$, etc?

Comment: @Binary198 I'm talking about the complexity of a formula defining the set of axioms in said theory. E.g. "computable = $\Delta^0_1$" (in the sense of the *arithmetic* hierarchy).

Comment: Ahh, ok. Thanks.

Comment: I assume that, since it's not explicitly stated in Wikipedia, that you mean that $\varphi \in \Delta^0_1 \leftrightarrow \varphi \in \Pi^0_1 \land \exists \psi (\psi \in \Sigma^0_1 \land \varphi \leftrightarrow \psi)$ .

Comment: @Binary198 It is in the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetical_hierarchy#The_arithmetical_hierarchy_of_sets_of_natural_numbers. Note that unlike the $\Sigma$ and $\Pi$ classes, there is no such thing as a $\Delta^0_1$ **formula**: $\Delta^0_1$-ness (and etc.) is a property of *sets*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134739/discussion-between-binary198-and-noah-schweber).

Comment: I don't understand. Isn't the least stable ordinal also the least $\Sigma^1_2$-reflecting ordinal? Doesn't that mean that it's the minimal model height of KP+$\Sigma^1_2$-reflection? Is that not a computably-axiomized theory?

Comment: @BorisDimitrov "Least $\Sigma^1_2$-reflecting ordinal" is **not** the same as "minimal height of a model of $\mathsf{KP}$+$\Sigma^1_2$-reflection." The issue is that we may have a very small model that *incorrectly thinks* that a certain ordinal is $\Sigma^1_2$-reflecting, due to the complexity of the second-order quantifier.

Comment: Isn't the least $\Sigma^1_1$-reflecting ordinal the minimal model height of KP+$\Sigma^1_1$-Reflection, though? If so, why would the pattern hold for $\Sigma^1_1$, but break at $\Sigma^1_2$?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Recently I've come across a sentence which I think is $\Sigma^0_1$ in arithmetical hierarchy but *not* $\Delta_1$ in Levy hierarchy - "there exists $n$ such that $n$ codes a ZFC-proof of 0=1". $\Delta_1$-ness of this sentence would imply absoluteness across all transitive models of ZFC, and also we need an unbounded existential quantifier to set up a variable with the value of $\omega$ (not sure how to do this with unbounded universal quantifiers instead.)

Comment: @BorisDimitrov I guess it may have to do with "upward persistence" phenomenon of $\Sigma_1$ formulae: if we can extend this concept but about the second-order quantifiers in a $\Sigma_1^1$ formula instead, we may get the result on KP+$\Sigma_1^1$-reflection. Then this modified upward persistence of $\Sigma_2^1$ formulae may fail the same way usual upward persistence fails for $\Sigma_2$ formulae